# Variable declaration at the end of typedef structure definition

Tags: c, struct, typedef, c89

We know that struct objects can be declared at the end of structure definition like so :

```c
struct vertex
{
float x,y,z;
}v1;
```

Is such a declaration of an object like `v1` 
possible while using typedef struct?

```c
typedef struct vertex
{
float x,y,z;
} vertex;
```

Is it mandatory to declare objects separately now with

```c
vertex v1;
```

can they not be appended at the end of struct definition in this case?

Comment: You can't do it because it doesn't make any sense. A typedef is a template for all variables to be created of that type. It isn't a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it cannot be.

`typedef` is used for creation of an alias / synonym for another type. It cannot be used for declaration of variables.

```
typedef struct ver
{
float x,y,z;
} vertex;
```

Here, `vertex` is same as `struct ver` (I changed the name slightly for better understanding).

Once the type (alias) is created, you use that to create a variable using another identifier, like

```
vertex v;
struct ver v1;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the 'storage class' `typedef`, then the names defined after the structure are the typedef names — aliases for the structure type.  So, `vertex` is a type name.  When you define the type name, you cannot also define any variables.